# C# - Using Linq get data if null value exist in query

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have two datatables,

```
var userList1 = from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                where myRow.Field<bool?>("IsActive1") == null 
                      ? true 
                      : myRow.Field<bool?>("IsActive1") == true
                select myRow;

var userList2 = from myRow in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                select myRow;
```

`dt1` table shows like this,

[image]

Using this Linq query,

```
var objUserSetUp1 = (from A in userList1
                     join B in userList2 
                     on new 
                     { 
                         UserId = A.Field<Int64?>("Id") == null 
                                      ? 0 
                                      : A.Field<Int64>("Id") 
                     } 
                     equals new 
                     { 
                         UserId = B.Field<Int64?>("UserId") == null 
                                      ? 0 
                                      : B.Field<Int64>("UserId") 
                     }
                     select new
                     {
                         UserId = A.Field<Int64>("Id"),
                         FirstName = A.Field<string>("FirstName"),
                         SurName = A.Field<string>("SurName"),
                         Computer_Name = A.Field<string>("Computer_Name"),
                         IP_Address = A.Field<string>("IP_Address"),
                         LogInTime = A.Field<string>("LogInTime") == null 
                                          ? "UnKnown" 
                                          : A.Field<string>("LogInTime"),
                         UserName = A.Field<string>("UserName"),
                         Password = A.Field<string>("Password"),
                         login_Id = A.Field<Int64?>("login_Id") == null 
                                        ? 0 : 
                                        A.Field<Int64?>("login_Id"),
                         docCount = B.Field<Int64>("docCount")
                     }).ToList();
```

How can I get if `UserId` is null also want to take `docCout` field value too. How can I do this inside the query?

Comment: I edited your post, in order to make it more readable. Pay attention on this, since it is very important for the readers of your post. A not well formed question is difficult to be read.

Comment: Thanks, @Christos. I will follow as you say.

Comment: @AbhilashJA You are welcome :)

Comment: @Rob , docCount is the field name of dt1 datatable. Actually I want docCount value too if UserId is DBNull. How can I get?

Comment: @AbhilashJA I'm not sure what you are asking exactly. I think you're asking about the join criteria?  If `A.id` has a value that does not exist in `B.UserId`, do you want to use the B row that has `UserID == null`?

Comment: @Rob exactly, I want that value if UserID == null. How can I  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a [Left Outer Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397895.aspx), where the default value for the outer join (ie when no matching record exists) is the `userList2` entry where `Field("UserId")` is `null`.

See below (untested, but you get the idea!):

```
    var objUserSetUp1 = (from A in userList1
                        join B in userList2 
                            on A.Field<Int64?>("Id") equals B.Field<Int64?>("UserId")
                            into BGroup
                        from C in BGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(userList2.Single(u => u.Field<Int64?>("UserId") == null))
                        select new
                        {
                            UserId = A.Field<Int64>("Id"),
                            FirstName = A.Field<string>("FirstName"),
                            SurName = A.Field<string>("SurName"),
                            Computer_Name = A.Field<string>("Computer_Name"),
                            IP_Address = A.Field<string>("IP_Address"),
                            LogInTime = A.Field<string>("LogInTime") == null
                                            ? "UnKnown"
                                            : A.Field<string>("LogInTime"),
                            UserName = A.Field<string>("UserName"),
                            Password = A.Field<string>("Password"),
                            login_Id = A.Field<Int64?>("login_Id") == null
                                        ? 0 :
                                        A.Field<Int64?>("login_Id"),
                            docCount = C.Field<Int64>("docCount")
                        }).ToList();
```